# Tabulator - Having Column Header Resize when Font Size Changes

Tags: tabulator

I am using [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) and the default "fitData" function to size the cells. This works exactly as intended when I a) Have a default font size set and b) change the row font size using the rowFormatter:

```
        rowFormatter:function(row){
        var rowData = row.getData();
        row.getElement().style.fontSize = config.body_font_size + "px";
```

The above works, however, when I want to change the font size of the column titles:

```
var curHeaders = document.getElementsByClassName("tabulator-col");
for (var i = 0; i < curHeaders.length; i++) {
    curHeaders[i].style.fontSize = fontSize.toString() + "px";
}
```

This changes all the column font sizes, but does not resize the column width appropriately. Is there a different class where I should assigning the font? Is there a way to apply this in a similar way to the rowFormatter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try and programatically alter elements inside Tabulator from outside the table. Because Tabulator uses a virtual DOM these changes can be overwritten at any point without notice.

If you need to format column header titles you should use a ***titleFormatter*** in the column definition for the column you want to change:

```
//define custom formatter
var customFormatter = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){

    //set font size
    cell.getElement().style.fontSize = fontSize.toString() + "px";

    return cell.getValue();
}

//in the column definition for a column
{title:"Name", field:"name", titleFormatter:customFormatter },
```

Full documentation on how to use formatters can be found here: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/format

If you need to keep using your approach then you can call the table ***redraw*** function to force the table to be rebuilt:

```
table.redraw(true);
```

Is there a reason you need to change it at run time rather than just making the changes in CSS?

Comment: The titleFormatter seems to be exactly what I am looking for. However, I am getting the error: 

`tabulator.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

I can clearly see when I console log the cell that it is working, though - it returns the `<div class='tabulator-col-title'></div>`
With the appropriate new font size. Any ideas?

Comment: That happens when you return an invailid value from the formatter, it must either be a string/number or a DOM element of type Node. If you post a copy of the formatter you are using i can provide some feedback

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in the 4.0.5 release that is causing the titleFormatter to only accept node returns instead of also allowing text. i have put a patch for this on the 4.1 branch and will include it in next weekends release

Comment: Version 4.1 launched today with a fix for your issue