# Working example to custom-format a column title/header?

Tags: tabulator

I have a formatter that works for column data, using column parameter `formatter`.  Using the same formatter with column parameter `titleformatter`, I get the error noted below.  Also, I don't understand why HTML in `title` parameter text seems not to work for `<b> ... </b>` but does work for other things (e.g., `<i> ... </i>`.  A working custom formatter example would help.  (I don't see this in Tabulator documentation.)  See this montage combining a column header and row header screenshot with common cell text---'bold' in the row looks bolder to me.

[Cell text comparison screenshot montage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEuXG.png)

I've tried emulating some posted sample code, but I get the same error as reported by @dagroj in his comment to @Oli Folkerd's answer (to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974988/tabulator-having-column-header-resize-when-font-size-changes/52975191#52975191)) about `titleformatter` --- viz. `tabulator.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`  (Mentioning that here because I don't yet have the reputation to comment there.)

[Here is a rendering of my CPT, without the titleformatter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnlzA.png)

Corresponding table constructor:

```
  "columnVertAlign": "bottom",
  "height": "100%",
  "layout": "fitColumns",
  "columns": [
    {
      "title": "<i> absolute_T<--T (noisyAnd)</i>",
      "columns": [
        {
          "title": "<b> NotCorrAnd_EffectiveHyp</b>",
          "field": "label",
          "align": "right",
          "headerSort": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "NotB_EffectiveHyp",
      "columns": [
        {
          "title": "<b>T</B>",
          "field": "true",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "<i>F</i>",
          "field": "false",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "<b> Belief </b>",
      "columns": [
        {
          "title": "odds",
          "field": "odds",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "log<sub>2</sub> odds",
          "field": "log2odds",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Formatter:

```
function truthFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();
    var cellElement = cell.getElement();
    if (cellValue == "T") {
    cellElement.style.backgroundColor = "#0000B3";
    cellElement.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
    cellElement.style.textAlign = "center";
    cellElement.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
    else if (cellValue == "F") {
    cellElement.style.backgroundColor = "#B30000";
    cellElement.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
    cellElement.style.textAlign = "center";
    cellElement.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
    else cellElement.style.color = "#000000";
    return cell.getValue();
}
```

Comment: can you post a copy of your title formater code so we can give you some feedback, it seems to be missing in the snippet you have posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column headers are by default styled to be bold, so adding a bold or strong tag will not make them any bolder. On a side not you are using a mix of lowercase and uppercase "b" in your tags

If you are getting that error it means that your formatter is not returning a valid value, it must either be a string/number or a DOM element of type Node.

Comment: Are the requirements different for a titleformatter than for a standard column formatter?  I am trying to use the same formatter for both.  It's working for entries in my first column, not for the title.

Comment: Did you see my screenshot?  It looks like no headers are bold.  (Compare "odds" in row and column labels---looks identical.)

Comment: looking at your screenshot the headers look bold to me, it is really easy to check, right click on the header element and inspect it, the inspector will tell you if it is bold or not

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in the 4.0.5 release that is causing the titleFormatter to only accept node returns instead of also allowing text. i have put a patch for this on the 4.1 branch and will include it in next weekends release

Comment: I see `font-weight: 700;`, inherited from `div.tabulator-header`.  In my row headers, `<b> ... </b>` gets `font-weight: bold;`.  The latter seems darker to me.

Comment: The weight for bold is 700, normal is 400

Comment: I gather that you are right about that equivalence.  However, the rendering seems different in rows than in column headers.  See my cell text comparison screenshot, just added---header text on top/right, row text on bottom/left.

Comment: Still working on the above bug?  Didn't see it listed among 4.1's fixes.  My table now renders when using the same formatter for `titleFormatter` that has already been working for (column) `formatter`, but it doesn't render the same/as expected.

Comment: It has indeed been fixed. given your custom formatter, it is not surprising there are differences. the are key differences between a cell and a header element that are not easy to replicate. for something as complicated as that i would usually suggest that you make the styling changes as CSS classes and then apply the class to the element which is a more robust and repeatable process. If you can let me know what you are expecting i can suggest an option, but it is probably worth opening another issue for that as the key issues of the html tag and the formatter error have been resolved.